# Что такое API понятным языком?

Tags: терминология

Что такое API понятным языком? (очень понятным)

Comment: Очень неплохое обьяснение вашего вопроса https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/52599/

Comment: Вы подошли к автомату с газировкой, кинули монеты, выбрали вид напитка и получили то что хотели. Вы взаимодействовали с ним посредством его "API".

Comment: Частный пример, если вам проще понимать от частного к общему. Возьмём к примеру стримерскую площадку "twitch.tv". Вам нужно написать мобильное приложение(отталкиваюсь от тега Android), которое отобразит онлайн(количество человек) на канале вашего друга. У твича есть свой API. Поэтому вы, вместо того чтобы, извиняюсь, мудохаться с алгоритмами(открывать канал и что - то там считать), просто делаете запрос к этому API, и в ответе получаете текущий онлайн. API сформирует ответ за вас.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Данный вопрос, очень хорошо раскрывается в статье "Что такое API" от 26.11.2012года  https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/52599/

Более заумно (Материал из Национальной библиотеки им. Н. Э. Баумана
https://ru.bmstu.wiki/API_(Application_Programming_Interface )

"API (англ. Application Programming Interface) - это набор определений, протоколов и инструментов для разработки ПО и приложений. API-интерфейс разрабатывается для упрощения создания программ, путем предоставления всех необходимых функциональных блоков. API может быть разработано для web систем, ОС и баз данных, предоставляя среду для разработки приложений используя конкретный язык программирования. Например, программист, который разрабатывает приложения для Android может использовать Android API для взаимодействия с аппаратной частью.)"

более по простому : API (Application Programming Interface) — это интерфейс программирования, интерфейс создания приложений. Если говорить более понятным языком, то API — это готовый код для упрощения жизни программисту. API в объектно-ориентированных языках, в простейшей форме представляется в виде набора классов со связанными списками методов. Например, в Java, если класс Scanner используется, необходимо импортировать библиотеку java.util.Scanner

"API создавался для того, чтобы программист реально мог облегчить задачу написания того или иного приложения благодаря использованию готового кода (например, функций)."

Однако Начинающим разработчикам НАДО ПОМНИТЬ что API это не только семантика и сигнатура функций стандартных классов языка программирования но и определяет функциональность, которую предоставляет программа (модуль, библиотека, api операционных систем), при этом API позволяет ***абстрагироваться от того, как именно эта функциональность реализована.***
НЕ следует пользоваться полуготовыми решениями! Учитесь думать своей головой API — это не готовые решения, это среда, интерфейс для создания своих проектов.

Comment: Честно говоря, раскрывает не очень хорошо. Какой-то набор ничего не объясняющих слов.

Comment: @Эникейщик Ответ раскрывается в указанное статье по ссылке, а указанные ниже цитаты нечто иное как требования сайта  ("Приведите краткую выдержку из прикрепленной статьи здесь, в виде ответа. Если ссылка будет удалена или изменена, ваш ответ перестанет быть актуальным. Подробнее о публикации ответов с ссылками на другие статьи и как опубликовать хороший ответ – Mr. Brightside»). Согласно которого мой ответ ранее, уже был отмечен автором вопроса как удовлетворительный и закрытый, однако удаленный по вышеуказанному правилу.

Comment: Если ссылка будет удалена или изменена, то и этот ответ перестанет быть актуальным. Нужно давать цитаты не для того, что формально выполнить правила, а для того, чтобы дать ответ на вопрос. Вы бы, прочитав свой ответ, поняли что такое API?

Comment: @Эникейщик я немного изменил ответ  и  думаю, что его достаточно.

Comment: Вы, кстати, обратили внимание, что эта так называемая статья находится в песочнице? Как вы думаете, почему?

Comment: Я бы этот ответ удалил и не позорился. Это какой-то Яндекс.Реферат, а не ответ.

Comment: @Эникейщик Возможно Вы и правы… я не писатель, может действительно плохо передаю свою мысль и выбираю главное. Однако главный посыл который я хочу передать человеку, задающему этот вопрос или тому кто его будет искать … то что программисты перестают быть художниками и все больше становятся малярами, если Вы понимаете о чем я. Используют то, что не понимают и самое главное не хотят понимать, не хотят разбираться….

Answer (score 7):

Попробую ну очень простым.

Там где-то было упоминание замороженных котлет... Ну так вот на примере этих самых котлет и давайте попробуем разобраться.

## Пример

Вы пришли домой с купленными котлетами и хотите их разогреть и скушать.

Вы знаете, что где-то в доме у Вас есть плита - Вы идете к ней. Будем считать, что плита, это некий ящичек (**объект**), с набором кнопок (**интерфейс**), который позволит Вам разогреть котлеты при правильном использовании.

Вы не знаете, как плита устроена внутри, но Вы знаете, что нужно нажимать, чтобы разогреть котлеты.

**Шаг №1 - включить плиту**

Вы находите кнопку "Вкл", нажимаете на нее и вот плита работает.

**Шаг №2 - настроить горелку**

Теперь нужно настроить нужную горелку, - отрегулировать силу огня/тепла (если электрическая). Для этого Вы пользуетесь уже другой кнопкой или регулятором. И в итоге настраиваете, ставите разогреваться котлеты.

## Интерфейсы повсюду

Подобные интерфейсы, позволяющие человеку взаимодействовать с другими предметами встречаются повсеместно.

Например, чтобы выполнять работу на заводе, когда оператору нужно распилить доску на станке. Тут оператор вводит параметры распила и запускает станок. Станок, по введенным в интерфейсе (это тоже API в своем роде) параметрам делает распил.

## А что программирование?

По такому же принципу работают API. Это некий "ящичек" с определенным интерфейсом, позволяющий Вам решать конкретные задачи.

"Все, что может быть оцифровано, будет оцифровано", поэтому сейчас есть API для работы с финансовой информацией, для работы с картотеками книг в библиотеках и... да почти с чем угодно.

Каждый день Вы взаимодействуете с API, сами того не подозревая - в лифте, в приложениях соц. сетей, настраивая навигацию в автомобиле.

Вот [тут](https://thequestion.ru/questions/80369/chto-takoe-api-nuzhno-obyasnenie-sovsem-dlya-chainika) можно прочитать чуть более сложный пример.

## Что-то более конкретное?

Предположим, что Вы создаете приложение для торговли на бирже.

С одной стороны у Вас есть клиент - приложение в телефоне. Но, это приложение должно куда-то "ходить", чтобы получить информацию о Ваших акциях.

Поэтому, с другой стороны имеется сервер. Нужная для клиента информация находится где-то на сервере, в БД и, чтобы получить ее, Вам нужно сделать вызов (повзаимодействовать с интерфейсом). Это то же самое, что нажать кнопку "вкл" на плите.

Получив данные, Вы, допустим, решаете продать одну акцию - Вы взаимодействуете с неким интерфейсом еще раз и отправляете данные, вида "*я хочу продать вот эту акцию*" и вот, Ваша акция продана и Вы стали чуть богаче.

Набор таких вызовов представляет из себя API. Все вместе эти вызовы позволяют вам торговать - точно так же, как вся плита целиком позволит Вам разогреть котлеты.

Comment: пример про биржу то что надо

Answer (score 4):

API это программный интерфейс, через который внешний мир взаимодействует с объектом. Если взять любую библиотеку или фреймворк, то в документации к ним будут описаны все возможные функции, которые можно вызвать и использовать. Множество этих функций и есть API данной библиотеки. То же самое можно сказать о множестве публичных мтодов некого класса. Обратите внимание, что приватные методы и свойства уже не будут частью API.

Answer (score 2):

API (Application Programming Interface) - описание того, каким образом взаимодействовать с объектом, как им пользоваться (на программном уровне).

Например: как пользоваться дверью.

```
У двери есть ручка - механизм, с помощью которого можно ею пользоваться.

Как открыть дверь:
1. встать перед дверью
2. если дверь закрыта
 2.1 взять за ручку
 2.2 потянуть на себя
3. если дверь открыта - ничего не делать

Как закрыть дверь:
1. встать перед дверью
2. если дверь открыта
  2.1 взять за ручку
  2.2 оттолкнуть от себя
3. если дверь закрыта - ничего не делать
```

Как пользоваться дверью с замком.

... тут интерфейс взаимодействия усложняется